# "Updating Python Interpreter" in Pycharm. What does it mean?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, anaconda

I notice that the bottom of my Pycharm IDE shows that there are 2 processes running. When I click on it, a panel opens that says my Python interpreter is updating.

[image: Updating Python Interpreter Panel Pycharm]

I'm not quite sure what is being updated here: is it Python? conda? Other packages (since there seems to be a few packages e.g. panda, PyQT popping up under the installation bar)?

This leads to my next question: how often will this keep happening, since this updating slows down my Pycharm quite a bit? Also, does it mean that conda packages automatically update? I'd always thought that you have to manually update them in the conda command prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you change interpreter in pycharm , pycharm first update all of the pre-installed packages. Because time to time many changes comes in packages, Pycharm take care of them.

Comment: Appreciate your answer Ayodhyankit Paul! Yeah I did change interpreter. So does that mean that Pycharm is merely "refreshing" the packages that come with this interpreter, but if I want to update the package I still have to do it in conda right? Also, does this mean that this will only pop up again only when I change interpreter the next time?

Comment: There can be many interpreters in your system so when you change and set to default, then condo first load them and update them along with index them. Afaik pycharm is advanced IDE and it takes care of auto-update of necessary modules.

Comment: So does that mean I don't have to worry about updating my 3rd-party packages with conda anymore, since Pycharm will coordinate the update automatically? And how often does this auto-update happen? Sorry to bother you with so many questions! I'm new to Pycharm so there are many things that confuse me.

Comment: Generally pycharm shows update for packages but if you work with some specific modules and want to keep them update regular then try https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20908

Comment: Just did ;) Thanks for your help Paul!

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul, your answer is still not clear to me, does PyCharm update modules without direct user's permission?

Comment: I have not changed my interpreter, but it's still effecting me

Answer (score 11):

Pycharm is *NOT* updating the remote interpreter. See [this discussion on the jetbrains feedback site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000615190/comments/360000206790).

In short, the message is badly worded - what's actually happening is downloading remote libraries, which are used for pydoc, method signatures, looking at library code etc...